# Is there a way to not allow the `UPDATE` directly using postgresql if that tuple is referenced somewhere?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

Let's say I have the classic example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE teams 
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying,
);

CREATE TABLE players 
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying,
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY players 
    ADD CONSTRAINT players_team_id_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES suppliers(id) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Is there a way to not allow the `UPDATE` of the team `name` directly using postgresql if that team is referenced somewhere?

I'm wondering if there is some kind of `ON UPDATE AVOID IF TEAM_ID IS REFERENCED`.

Is this possible directly using postgresql or should I use custom backend code?

Comment: You could make the `name` the primary key, rather than using a generated ID. It will use a bit more space and for large analytical queries it might also be a bit slower though.

Comment: `name` is an example of many more fields I need to avoid update.

Comment: A database constraint cannot do what you need. However, a pre-update trigger could perform the validation.

Comment: What do you think about `ON UPDATE RESTRICT`?

Comment: @FredHors: That would restrict the update of the id, not the name. By the way, why you use BIGINT? Do you really expect more than 2 billion teams or players?

Comment: What is the problem with bigint?

Answer (score 0):

ON UPDATE RESTRICT does not allow updates for referenced row

Comment: Is it there for POSTGRESQL too?

Comment: @FredHors check out this link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html,  at the end of the page is mentions different constraints on update and delete for foreign keys

Comment: I tried your suggestion but its only for restrict the update of the `id`, not the `name`, unfortunately.

Comment: you can use ON UPDATE RESTRICT for foreign keys

Comment: I am not sure but I think you can use triggers in the database for this use case. you can write an update trigger in the database and in the update trigger rollback the transaction if the row is a referenced row